# Apache Ant Zip tag performance

Tags: apache, ant

I am using Apache Ant1.7 for our build process. In our build.xml I wrote the following line for zip a folder.

```
<zip destfile="${build.lib.dir}/HzERM_Server_Side_workarea.zip">
        <fileset dir="${base.working.dir}"/>
</zip>
```

Problem is.... I am trying to zip 3.20GB size of folder, it is taking nearly 24 minutes 20 secs to zip the folder. Could you please help me how to improve its performance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this was a performance bug in Ant that has been fixed in version 1.8.1. The code building the zip was using Hashtable incorrectly resulting in O(n) instead of O(1) performance.

See this blog for the details: http://blog.zorinaq.com/?e=16

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) ANT task and get it to run an external compression tool, such as 7Zip with command line instructions.